# How to verify ios In-App Purchase with different account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an app with non-consumable products. My app need to register and log in for service.

I figure out that the products that user has bought are tied with Apple ID. If user use same Apple ID but different accounts from my server, how will I verify them whether the account buy the product or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `original_transaction_id` to validate it.

Steps-

1. When any user make a payment, validate the receipt on server.
2. If a valid payment then update paid in your database and store
   `original_transaction_id` of that receipt.
3. Next time if the user use same Apple ID, after validating the receipt, check if the `original_transaction_id` exists in the database or not. If already
   exists means user is using same Apple ID for other accounts too,
   else its using its Apple ID to make payment first time.

Comment: Thanks for the help!